# init new class instance with args object parameter which conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I've a class and a protocol into myModel.swift

```
public protocol IModelArgs{
    var name: String { get set};
    var surname: String { get set};
}

public class Model {
    var name: String;
    var surname: String;
    init(args: IModelArgs) {
        self.name = args.name;
        self.surname = args.surname;
    }
}
```

IModelArgs is the protocol of arguments object passed to Model constructor.
Into another file I need to create the instance of Model class, but I'm not able to pass args object to constructor: What I'm wrong?

```
let myM = Model(args: ("T1","T2"));
```

Comment: Why exactly are you using a protocol here? Why not just have an initialiser that takes a `name:` and `surname:` parameter?

Comment: Unrelated, but note that you don't need to end statements with semicolons (unless to separate multiple statements on a single line).

Comment: Your argument object does not conform to protocol. I would advise you to use struct conforming to your protocol. And also I think you do not want argument to be get set but get only as you will not change it after init.

Comment: @Hamish because now args object have just name and surname, but next will become a more complex object which I will reuse in other contexts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem in your case that `("T1","T2")` is a tuple and not the object that conform your protocol. In your case it should look like this:

```
struct ArgsObject: IModelArgs {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
}

let myM = Model(args: ArgsObject(name: "someName", surname: "someSurname"))
```

But if you want to use the protocol only to pass an object to the constructor, you do not need to do this. Create `struct` for it like this:

```
struct ArgsObject {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
}

class Model {
    var name: String
    var surname: String

    init(args: ArgsObject) {
        self.name = args.name
        self.surname = args.surname
    }
}

let myM = Model(args: ArgsObject(name: "someName", surname: "someSurname"))
```

**Few optional comments**

Don't use `;` and protocol names like `ISomething`, it's not the Java